# FileProvider - Internal Storage - Failed to find configured root that contains

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

I know that there are a lot of questions at SO about this problem. I tried about 10 different approaches and i couldn't make it work right. I always get next error:

```
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /file:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/app.kwork/files/IMG-afbfdc57c016fb1ff7dd983a056edffa-V.jpg
```

[Official tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing.html) also didn't help. I'll share my code below, maybe i do something wrong, and you know what exactly is wrong here..

Manifest:

```
  <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="app.kwork.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>
```

provider_paths.xml

```
<paths>
    <files-path path="." name="files" />
</paths>
```

I save files into:

```
 File futureStudioIconFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null) + File.separator + fileName);
```

Example of the file path:   file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/app.kwork/files/IMG-afbfdc57c016fb1ff7dd983a056edffa-V.jpg

And try to share this file with next code:

```
  public void openFile(String filePath){
        File file = new File(filePath);
        Log.d(TAG, "openFile: filePath: " + filePath);
        Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "app.kwork.provider", file);

        MimeTypeMap myMime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        Intent newIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        String mimeType = myMime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(Utils.fileExt(filePath));
        newIntent.setDataAndType(photoURI,mimeType);
        newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        try {
            context.startActivity(newIntent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "No handler for this type of file.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```

I tried different authorities and paths in xml, but i'm here now.

UPD: **Testing on Android Oreo**

Answer (score 1):

Per the [FileProvider documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html), it is `<external-files-path>` that corresponds with `getExternalFilesDir()` - the `<files-path>` you are using corresponds with `getFilesDir()`.

You must change your `paths.xml` to use `<external-files-path>` or store your files in `getFilesDir()`.

Comment: As i said, i tried a lot of variants, included yours.

Comment: <paths>
    <external-files-path path="." name="files" />
</paths> doesn't wotk

Answer (score 1):

> Example of the file path: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/app.kwork/files/IMG-afbfdc57c016fb1ff7dd983a056edffa-V.jpg

This is not a file path. This is a `Uri`.

The file path is `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/app.kwork/files/IMG-afbfdc57c016fb1ff7dd983a056edffa-V.jpg`.

Do not pass a string form of a `Uri` to the `File` constructor. You will wind up with a malformed `File`, and `getUriForFile()` will not be able to deal with that malformed `File`.